# Is it ok to have a Child Category appear in multiple Parent Categories?

Tags: seo, url, categories

I am currrently looking at creating the following URL:

1. `www.example.com/floral-canvas-prints/daffodils`

This is pretty self explanatory.  A user would expect the above URL to take them to a product page, displaying Daffodil Canvas Prints.

Since Daffodils are both a Perennial and Spring Flower, I am looking at also creating dedicated `Spring Flowers` and `Perennial Flowers` product Categories.  As such, creating the following URLs:

2. `www.example.com/floral-canvas-prints/spring-flowers`
3. `www.example.com/floral-canvas-prints/perennial-flowers`

My thought process being, the above additional Categories would not only allow the targeting of a broader range of specific Keywords but also allow visitors to browse products from varying angles.  Furthermore, the additional Categories would allow for the creation of Category specific Facet Navigation, focused on user intent.  Collectively, working together to improve user experience.

Where my uncertainties lie, is in the placement of the `/daffodils/` product Category.

Firstly, are the above URL structures okay?   I feel there is something 'out of order' in that the first URL has a specific Flower within the second directory, whilst in the 2nd and 3rd URLs, the second directory consist of collective Nouns; which Daffodils would be within.  Would this be problematic, from a search engine perspective?

Secondly, is the first URL okay or should I consider appending the `/daffodil/` directory to the 2nd and 3rd URL examples, as follows:

4. `www.example.com/floral-canvas-prints/spring-flowers/daffodils`
5. `www.example.com/floral-canvas-prints/perennial-flowers/daffodils`

My thinking with this possible restructure, being that by appending, it may help boost search engines' topical understanding of each directory, by the mutually beneficial signals that are sent between each directory through internal linking etc.

My instincts say, that I should stick with the above (1, 2 and 3) URL examples.

Let's say I do stick with the following URL structure:

6. `www.example.com/floral-canvas-prints/spring-flowers`

Would the fact that the above URL contained all Spring Flower products be enough of a signal for the `/spring-flowers/` Category, that appending `/daffodils/` to it, would be overkill?  As such, it would be fine to have `/daffodils/` as a separate product Category, rather than it being included within each of the `/spring-flowers/` and `/perennial-flowers/` product Categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more about site structure and less about SEO. SEO-wise, the problem would be that you want your daffodils page to have one SEO ranking and not have it divided in two (or more) different ones based on the journey your visitor makes in your site.

This can be solved by using canonical tags. The daffodils page will be the url to which the x/..../daffodils and y/..../daffodils and z/..../daffodils urls will point to. So in the end, you can reach the same page about daffodils via multiple paths without bleeding SEO ranking all over different urls.

Comment: I am often guilty in over analysing a situation and forgetting the basics at time.  Regardless, you are right! :-)